# Fill Form in Play Framework (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, checkbox, playframework

I'm making checkboxes and using Scala, I found nice [example](https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/play-example-form/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java) but in Java. But I couldn't convert it to Scala.
This is Java code:

```
Form<StudentFormData> formData = Form.form(StudentFormData.class).fill(studentData);
```

Scala's play.api.data.Form class doesn't have "fill" and "form" methods like Java's play.data.Form. How I can create Form in Scala?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms See the section called "Fill values". There's also a few small examples of how forms are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I use to get data from the Form and generate an object Location.

```
  def add = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    val data = LocationForm.form.bindFromRequest.get

    Locations.create(Some(data.venueName), data.lat, data.lon)

    Redirect(routes.LocationController.all)   }
```